# Count sequence within a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a following problem. Suppose I have this dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'Name': ['c', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'd', 'd'], 'Project': ['aa','ab','bc', 'aa', 'ab','aa', 'ab','ca', 'cb'], 
     'col2': [3, 4, 0, 6, 45, 6, -3, 8, -3]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I need to add a new column that add a number to each project per name. Desired output is:

```
import pandas as pd

dnew = {'Name': ['c', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'd', 'd'], 'Project': ['aa','ab','bc', 'aa', 'ab','aa', 'ab','ca', 'cb'], 
     'col2': [3, 4, 0, 6, 45, 6, -3, 8, -3], 'New_column': ['1', '1','1','2', '2','2','2','3','3']}

NEWdf = pd.DataFrame(data=dnew)
```

In other words: 'aa','ab','bc' in Project occurs in the first rows, so I add 1 to the new column. 'aa', 'ab' is the second Project from the beginning. It occurs for Name 'a' and 'b', so I add 2 to the both new column. 'ca', 'cb' is the third project and it occurs only for name 'd', so I add 3 only to the name 'd'.

I tried to combine groupby with a for loop, but it did not worked to me. Thanks a lot for a help!

Comment: cant understand your problem... what did you try with your input df??

Comment: @SubbuVidyaSekar is it now clear?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [`networkx`](https://pypi.org/project/networkx/) since `Name` and `Project` are related , you can use:

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'Name', 'Project')
l = list(nx.connected_components(G))
s = pd.Series(map(list,l)).explode()
df['new'] = df['Project'].map({v:k for k,v in s.items()}).add(1)
```

---

```
print(df)

  Name Project  col2  new
0    a      aa     3    1
1    a      ab     4    1
2    b      bb     6    2
3    b      bc     6    2
4    c      aa     6    1
5    c      ab     6    1
```

Comment: Nice one! +1  This is a great answer.

Comment: Thanks fo reply. Your solution is good, but works only if Name has always length 2. I have slightly modified my example. Do you know how to adjust your code that it will still work, please?